# Do questions about SDL belong on Stack Overflow or Game Development?

Tags: discussion, scope

Where should people put these questions?

Or it does not matter where we ask questions about [SDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer)?

Comment: What is SDL in the first place?

Comment: @rene A graphics engine IIRC.

Comment: That helps a bit @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Is it a question about programming with SDL, or a question about SDL in general?

Comment: It entirely depends on the question you're going to ask. Best bet it to read through the help center of each respective site to determine the best fit.

Comment: Specific programming questions about using SDL seem just as on-topic on SO as specific programming questions about using other libraries.  That said, if you're programming a game and have a question specific to game development, you _may_ find the right people to answer on Game Dev (I've never been there, so I wouldn't know).  In addition to reading the help centers to see what's on-topic, I'd browse existing questions on each site to get a feel for what questions _get good answers in practice_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SDL](http://libsdl.org) is simply an abstraction layer:

> Simple DirectMedia Layer is a cross-platform development library designed to provide low level access to audio, keyboard, mouse, joystick, and graphics hardware via OpenGL and Direct3D.

Whilst it can be ([and often is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_using_SDL)) used to develop games, there's nothing to stop it from being used for things, like, say, [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html):

> ‘-curses’
>
> Normally, QEMU uses SDL to display the VGA output. With this option, QEMU can display the VGA output when in text mode using a curses/ncurses interface. Nothing is displayed in graphical mode.

General SDL programming questions belong on Stack Overflow. Game development questions could potentially go on either site, so long as they comply with [the rules](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).